# Sorting nodes with getting all childs from node parent(get array of childs)

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jstree

I need rearrange menu when I move node. I think the js script should sending with ajax new order of nodes in parent. But I don't understand how to get array of childs.
For example:

**List**

- Test node [id=1]
- Test node 2 [id=2]

  - Sub node 1 [id=5]
  - Sub node 2 [id=4]
  - Sub node 3 [id=3]
- Test node 3 [id=6]

And when I move Sub node 1 after Sub node 3

**Changed List**

- Test node [id=1]
- Test node 2 [id=2]

  - Sub node 2 [id=4]
  - Sub node 3 [id=3]
  - Sub node 1 [id=5]
- Test node 3 [id=6]

And Array which was sended to server-side script:

**Array(4,3,5)**

How to get that array of childs when i moving node?

Comment: How are you 'moving' these nodes, can you show the JavaScript/jQuery that handles this as well as the relevant HTML? You should post enough code that we can reproduce your problem (see: "[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"). And do you want to get the array of nodes (presumably their `id`s?) in JavaScript (as the question's tags suggest) or in PHP (as your own posted answer would suggest)?

Comment: I moving these with jstree plugin for jquery as the question's tags suggest and I want to get the of nodes in JavaScript. I didn't find answer for that and I'm use for it PHP language but I would prefer get this array in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you, but you need to show the actual code that is used; the html and the JavaScript, if that uses a plugin then show the call you make to that plugin. But without code in the question we can't offer code to answer the question: please, read the MCVE page. Then improve your question and help us to help you.

Comment: Thank you for advices, I'll keep it in mind next time. I solved that problem and I think about complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved that problem. I don't know if it is possible with only jstree API, but I write code which working on the same basis. I use for this PHP, but in this language I programming.
This is PHP code:

```
$id=intval($_REQUEST['id']);
$parent=intval($_REQUEST['parent']);
$position=intval($_REQUEST['position']);
$r=dbAll('select `id` from `menu` where `parent_id`='.$parent.' order by `order`');
$array=array();
foreach($r as $v)
    $array[]=$v['id'];
if(($key = array_search($id, $array)) !== false) {
    unset($array[$key]);
}
$insert=array($id);
array_splice( $array, $position, 0, $insert );
$array=array_values($array);
$i=1;
foreach($array as $val){
    dbQuery('update `menu` set `order`='.$i.',`parent_id`='.$parent.' where `id`='.$val);
    $i++;
}
```

Function dbAll() is used to get all matching records and Function dbQuery() is used to send mysqli query.